# How to convert the body of a client response to a Mono of a certain type?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

So, I send a request using the WebClient and after retrieving the response using exchange() I need to extract the body to a Mono of Object_1. The function needs to return Mono>. Normally you would use bodyToMono(SomeObject.class) but this doesn't work in this case.

```
public Mono<Object1<Object2>> getAll(String someParam) {

       return WebClient.create(this.baseUrl)
                .get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/some_path")
                        .queryParam("someParam", someParam)
                        .build())
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(????));

    }
```

I am trying to figure out what to put inside the bodyToMono()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do that with the overload of [`bodyToMono`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.ResponseSpec.html#bodyToMono-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-) that takes a [`ParameterizedTypeReference`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html).

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Object1<Object2>> typeRef =
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<Object1<Object2>>() {};
// . . .
.flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(typeRef));
```

You could write it inline, if you prefer and don't find it too hard to read:

```
.flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<Object1<Object2>>() {}));
```